# How to update Tencent Gaming Buddy offline

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

I play PUBG Mobile on Tencent Gaming Buddy and I have problem in updating PUBG in Tencent Gaming Buddy using the conventional way (I mean using the emulator itself). The problem is that my internet connection is not good and it sometimes disconnects, and for updating PUBG a constant internet connection is required. If my internet connection disconnects for even one second, Tencent Gaming Buddy restarts the update.

Is there any way for me to download the updated game files on my mobile phone and copy and paste that into the Tencent Gaming Buddy folder, so that I don't have to update PUBG using the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

I can say for sure that it is possible, but the method requires the language of Tencent Gaming buddy to be changed from English to Chinese which makes this task difficult to achieve. Also it would be hard to explain it in words so you may search for video tutorials on how to do that.

My recommended solution to this problem is using any other Android x86 based emulator. [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/), [Prime OS](https://primeos.in/download/), [Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/) and [LD Player](https://www.ldplayer.net/) are some of the best ones. The next step is to update the game in your android phone and then extract the APK (using any APK extractor easily available on Play Store) and copy the obb files to your PC. Then uninstall and reinstall the game on the emulator using these files.

The same method applies to Tencent Gaming Buddy but as an additional step you need to download a file explorer from its inbuilt store and proceed with the above steps. Its very hard if you don't know Chinese and therefore you will need to play a video tutorial side by side or use Google translate.